# How to make same cURL request in android java?

Tags: java, android, curl

I cannot understand request below for cURL:

```
    curl -X POST -u "client_id:secret" \
  https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=password \
  -d username={username} -d password={password}
```

How can I make same request in java (Android)?
Now, I try so:

```
String auth = vcs.getKey() + ":" + vcs.getSecret();
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encode(auth.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
URL url = new URL("https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "password");
connection.setRequestProperty("username", mLogin);
connection.setRequestProperty("password", mPassword);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the post parameters with at request header. Remove the last three and replace with below:

```
String params = "grant_type=password&username=xyz&password="+ java.net.URLEncoder.encode("urp&^!ass", "UTF-8");
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(params);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try it!