# How to make this paypal curl request in java

Tags: android, http, curl

This is my Curl request how to request it from android apps,

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \  
     -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \  
     -u "client_id:secret" \  
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

And I spend a lot of time but didn't get anything. And `HttpClient` also deprecated. So please provide the solution to do it.

And also I have seen the following **SO** links but I didn't get anything,
[Https post request using curl : Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315946/https-post-request-using-curl-android)

[How to make same cURL request in android java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521365/how-to-make-same-curl-request-in-android-java)

And much more. Please help.

Comment: You can use this instead of deprecated HttpClient.

https://github.com/square/okhttp

Answer (score 0):

Right way is to use: [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Lower level right way : [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp)